# Minecraft server start batch file not executing in cmd but no error

Tags: java, batch-file, server, minecraft-forge

im in need of help right now since i don't understand why it not working, basically when i try to run the batch file to start the minecraft server (Java) it open a cmd window but it just say Press any key to continue and nothing it doesn't start the server file whatsoever but when i double click the file, it does execute but i need to execute it from the batch file to get it to run on more memory than 200mb. Here is what the command i tried to do:  @echo off
java -Xmx4G -Xms3G -jar server.jar
pause
(Current one)
@echo off
java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar server.jar
pause (Another try i made)

java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.jar (Another one)

java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar server.jar (Another one again)
And yes the batch file is on ANSI Yes i have tred to execute it from the batch file (No success) cmd too (No success just continue to give Press any key to continue) Yes i have tried to execute it with win+r and yes i have tried to execute it without any argumant  and it still happen im out of ideas now of whatr caused the error im using java 1.8.0 build 311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution i just needed to install java 1.8 build 251 x86 to fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

make sure you update to the correct build of JDK which Minecraft uses. Example 1.16 uses Java SE 8, 1.17 uses Java SE 16, and 1.18 uses Java SE 17. (you can also use inbuilt JDK of Minecraft if you like)
Make sure you download the right Minecraft version for the server.jar(Because each server.jar is different in each version partly because it's the compilation process from Mojang.), Or You Can Download The Latest Ones.